# gurobi milp model to maximize npv

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to model a simple inventory maximizing income with gurobi MILP 
but i have been getting trouble about how to write the objective function for Net Present Value Maximizing.

an array A=np.random.randint(100,1500,100)
is the value from every 100 items in the inventory

```
from gurobipy import *

val=A

m = Model()
n = len(val) # number of items

# Indicator variable for each item
x = {}
for i in range(n):
    x[i] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d" % i)
#Indicator variable for each period of operation
prd={}
for u in range(7):
    prd[u]=m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY name="prd%d" % u)

m.update()

# Set objective
m.setObjective((quicksum((quicksum((val[i])*x[i] for i in range(n)))/(1+0.1**(u+1)))*prd[u] for u in range(7))), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

if this is the right way to model this type of problem the next step is to add constrains to only use an item at a single period of time.

Answer (score 0):

`quicksum()` evaluates a linear expression; you need to convert your nested expressions into a single linear expression.  You can do this by computing the coefficient values.